# How to add an HTML button

Tags: html, go

I'm building a web app (well at least one page on it) that shows the results of pings to different IPs.

I have no probs on Go displaying them on an HTML page. The simple thing I can't do (and I read so many tuto/threads that I'm lost and don't know what to do....) is to create a button "Refresh" that could just call back the "pingip" function i created in Go file.

Anyone has a concrete/"easy" example on how I could do this?

Comment: You can't call a function on your server directly from the browser. You have to make some kind of HTTP call from the browser (page load, form submission, or AJAX-type call from JavaScript), and have it accepted by a handler on the server, which can then execute any Go code you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a HTTP Handler for your Go program, which is what is serving the page - then you can have the button simply do a window.reload() through JavaScript, which will reload the page in the browser and re-invoke the Go script.

If you want this to happen without a reload, then you'd have to create a different HTTP Route and use AJAX (look up the fetch method in JavaScript), get the results over the network (maybe as JSON) and then update the data in the frontend.

Comment: That is a simple and nice answer. I'll try today, thank you !